# Bit Integers in C

Tags: c

I am just trying to do a problem in C that may give us 64 bit integers. It cannot support in displaying such big number. So what can i do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
long int a,b,n,c;
scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&a,&b,&n);
n-=2;
while(n--){
    c=(b*b)+a;
    a=b;
    b=c;
}
printf("%ld",c);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use type `long long` which is at least 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `%lld`.

```
scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&a,&b,&n);
printf("%lld",c);
```

But `long int` is not an 64bit integer. Use `long long int` or `int64_t` from `inttypes.h`.

Comment: To be clear, `a`, `b`, `c` and `n`  must have type `long long int` in order to use `%lld`. There is a different format specifier for `int64_t`.

Comment: `long int` might be a 64 bit integer, but it isn't required to be one.

Comment: The `"%lld"` format specifier tells `scanf` or `printf` that the units are `long long int`, yes. Don't use `"%lld"` in conjunction with `int64_t`; use `"%"PRId64` for `printf` or `"%"SCNd64` for `scanf`.

Comment: `int64_t` **may** be defined in `stdint.h`, not `inttypes.h`. The latter just contains the format specifiers for the types defined in `stdint.h`.

Comment: 1002992 integer length......if 123 has a length of 3....can i display upto that extent